# Problems injecting services in integration test

Tags: testing, grails, integration-testing, grails-2.1

I have a similar problem that [Integration testing Grails services with injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285270/integration-testing-grails-services-with-injection) with this code:

```
@TestFor(DocumentosService)
class DocumentosServiceTest extends GroovyTestCase  {
    def myService
    void testEnvioEmailDocumento() {
        assert myService != null
    }
}
```

When the test is executed myService is always null. 
Why myService is not being injected?
I'm using grails 2.1

Updated (2/6/2013) following Burt Beckwith's instructions:

```
class DocumentosServiceTest extends GroovyTestCase  {
    def myService
    def documentosService
    void testEnvioEmailDocumento() {
        assert documentosService != null
        assert myService != null
    }
}
```

Now documentosService is null too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@TestFor(DocumentosService)` since that's for unit tests. Add a regular dependency injection for the service, in this case it looks like it would be `def documentosService`

Comment: This has no effect at all. I'll edit the question with your recomendations.

Comment: So the class name of the service is `DocumentosService` and it's under `grails-app/services`, and the test class is under `src/test/integration`? Try running `grails clean` - it often fixes weird problems like this.

Comment: `grails clean` doesn't help, but the test is under `test/integration`, no under `src/test/integration`. If I put it in `src/test/integration` I can't run it from GGTS.

Comment: I can't run the test from command line. Also point that the command line generates the test file under `test` folder not under the `src/test`.